# Néologisme "réfléchissaguez"

Tags: choix-de-mot, néologismes

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> c'est passer à temps qu'il faut ! le Ciel est pas ouvert des siècles !
> vous  **réfléchissaguez**, blavez, il clôt ! Salut !

En plus de *réfléchir*, quel serait l'autre mot utilisé dans la formation de *réfléchissaguez* ?

Comment: Je dirais que c'est "divaguer". Dans le sens de réfléchir à des choses qui nous éloignent du sujet initial. Mais sans le contexte je ne sais pas si ça colle.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2):

Il s'agit probablement du suffixe -aguer, suffixe péjoratif. Peu utilisé. On connaît [ronflaguer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ronflaguer) qui a ses entrées dans les dictionnaires. Peut-être d'origine méridionale, parce que ça fait penser à [caguer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/caguer). Donc *réfléchir* mais de façon péjorative, insinuant probablement que ça ne sert à rien de réfléchir.